# Calibrate trapezoidal distortion for single plane

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

[image]
This is the image I want to calibrate. The distance and angle is always fixed. With the normal method, I am able to calibrate the radial distortion to an extent(even using this one single image). But I am unable to remove the trapezoidal distortion. To avoid the problem of the corners not being detected properly, I am clicking all the corners manually using `setMouseCallback`. But still the problem persists.

Comment: There should be no problem to detect the corners with this image. Clicking manually will likely not be accurate enough. At least run `cv::cornerSubPix` on your manually found corners.

Comment: @HannesOvrén : I tried manual corner detection just to make sure that the improper corner detection shouldn't be the problem. But how can I reduce the trapezoidal distortion? I'm able to reduce the radial distortion.